# Adding descriptions to items of a list in R

Tags: r, list

Is there a way to add descriptions to items in a list in R? I want to combine four dataframes into a list, but along with the name of each dataframe in the list, I want the list to contain a brief description of the dataframe as well.

For example, I want a line to do something like what my last line in the below code (pseudocoded) would do.

```
a <- matrix(rnorm(9), nrow=3, ncol=3)
b <- matrix(rnorm(9), nrow=3, ncol=3)
c <- matrix(rnorm(9), nrow=3, ncol=3)
d <- matrix(rnorm(9), nrow=3, ncol=3)
dat <- list(a, b, c, d)
names(dat) <- c("subject_info", "sample_info", "study_info", "test_info")
# description(dat$subject_info) <- "Subject-by-subject summary of results from the clinical trial"
```

Comment: Can you add a small reproducible example so that it is more clear because this looks more general

Comment: Maybe you could use an attribute. `dat <- iris` then `attr(dat, "description") <- "the iris dataset"`, then `list(iris = dat)`.

Comment: @akrun done, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Do you need an `attribute` or something else

Comment: Attribute is good, but is there something that will print by default every time in print the list?

Comment: `lapply(dat, function(x) {attr(x, "description") <-  "Subject-by-subject summary of results from the clinical trial"; x})`

Comment: The attributes are printed by default, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing from [@akrun's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60286250/adding-descriptions-to-items-of-a-list-in-r#comment106638926_60286250), the natural way of doing this is to use R's concept of `help("attributes")`. See also [Advanced R by Hadley Wickham](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html).

If you want to automate the task of getting and setting a special attribute, in this case the attribute `"description"`, define getter and setter functions.

```
description <- function(x){
  attr(x, "description")
}
`description<-` <- function(x, value){
  attr(x, "description") <- value
  x
}

description(dat$subject_info) <- "Subject-by-subject summary of results from the clinical trial"
```

Now see if it worked.

```
description(dat$subject_info)
#[1] "Subject-by-subject summary of results from the clinical trial"
```

**Note.**

Some base R functions with long names that are used many times have short name forms. An example is `coefficients` and the equivalent `coef`. If you plan to use these functions, you could define short name aliases.

```
# aliases
descr <- description
`descr<-` <- `description<-`

descr(dat$sample_info) <- "A test"
descr(dat$sample_info)
#[1] "A test"

lapply(dat, descr)
```